# Can't access my files in ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, file-io, file-permissions

I'm having a very difficult time. I am running windows 2008 server, I have an Able Commerce site using ASP.NET with C#. I'm writing an automated task that will ftp some xml files down into a local directory on our web server and then the program parses the xml file and saves information to our database. The problem, once I save the files to our local directory, my program has no access to the files. The NETWORK SERVICE user permissions isn't being inherited by the xml files so my program can't do anything with them. I can manually change the permissions, but this wouldn't be automated and won't work. How can I get this to work? help please, it's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use [Windows impersonationand](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=Windows+Impersonation+using+C%23&meta=&aq=f&oq=) open the XML file?